# Overriding of current TracerProvider is not allowed

Tags: python, dependency-injection, open-telemetry

I'm trying to write an opentelemetry provider for python-dependency-injector but for some reason, my traces are not sent and I get an error like - `Failed to export batch. Status code: StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE`

My provider:

```py
from dependency_injector import providers
from opentelemetry import trace
from opentelemetry.exporter.jaeger.proto import grpc
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace import TracerProvider
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace.export import BatchSpanProcessor

class OpenTelemetryProvider(providers.Provider):
    def _provide(self, *args, **kwargs):
        trace.set_tracer_provider(TracerProvider())
        tracer = trace.get_tracer(__name__)

        jaeger_exporter = grpc.JaegerExporter(
            collector_endpoint="localhost:14250",
            insecure=True,
        )

        # create a BatchSpanProcessor and add the exporter to it
        span_processor = BatchSpanProcessor(jaeger_exporter)

        # add to the tracer factory
        trace.get_tracer_provider().add_span_processor(span_processor)

        with tracer.start_as_current_span("foo") as span:
            print(span._context.span_id)
            print("Hello world!")

        return tracer
```

Answer (score 1):

This error originates inside TracerProvider, and the reason is because the internal _TRACER_PROVIDER_SET_ONCE object can only be initialized once as a singleton and then is not allowed to be written over: https://opentelemetry-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/opentelemetry/trace.html

This is intentional, and by design: https://opentelemetry.io/docs/concepts/signals/traces/#tracer-provider

I was encountering the `Overriding of current TracerProvider is not allowed` warning too. My logging output was not showing up either. I have another Windows laptop and some deployed solutions on VMs where I was not encountering this, but now I seem unable to use this in conjunction with Azure Monitor.

My current solution is to just remove use of Azure Monitor since I am not tied to it anymore. This has fixed it for me. For you, there must be another source registering a TracerProvider either before or after you register yours, leading to this error. You need to find why TracerProvider is being set twice, and remove the extra instance.

In my opinion, the use of a singleton and the inability to override the TracerProvider is very annoying since many other libraries/SDKs will initialize it on your behalf, thus leading to inevitable conflicts between these libraries and/or custom implementations.

There is more information related to this on this Closed GitHub thread as well: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-python/issues/1159 .